# UWP: Garbage collection Gen 2 still happens inside a NoGCRegion

Tags: c#, memory-management, uwp, garbage-collection

In my UWP app I need to perform a critical section for few seconds, when I need to be sure that the Garbage collector is not invoked.

So, I call

```
const long TOTAL_GC_ALLOWED = 1024L * 1024 * 240; // 240 MB, it seems max allowed is 244 for Workstations 64 bits
    try
    {
        bool res = GC.TryStartNoGCRegion(TOTAL_GC_ALLOWED);
        if (!res)
            s_log.ErrorFormat("Cannot allocate noGC Region!");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        s_log.WarnFormat("Cannot start NoGCRegion");
    }
```

Unfortunately, even if the method `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion()` returns `true`, I still see the same amount of GarbageCollection of Gen 2 as in the case when I don't call this method.

Please also notice that I am trying on a machine with 16 GB of RAM, of which only 9GB are used by the whole O.S. when I was doing my tests.

What am I doing wrong?

How can I achieve to suppress the GC (for a limited amount of time)?

Comment: When you set the size as 240MB, did you receive the exception or did it return true? And how did you see the amount of GarbageCollection of Gen 2?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT it returns true.In the profiler of Visual Studio I see continuous event of GC Gen 2, everytime with 30/40 objects claimed

Comment: Can you tell us why do you want to suppress the GC? What do you want to accomplish? And how long is a limited amount of time?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT I have a complex gesture that does a lot of stuff on the UI, while another couple of background threads are preparing content to be shown in the UI thread. I need this gesture to run at 60 fps. I noticed that there are few hic-hups in this gesture, and using Visual Studio profiler, I found that those hic-hups correspond exactly to periods when GC Gen 2 kicks-in. The gesture can last for no more than 10 seconds, during which we allocate no more than 100 MB of RAM (again, measured both with Visual Studio profiler and .NETMemory by JetBrains)